# Tensorflow MNIST (Weight and bias variables)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm learning how to use Tensorflow with the MNIST tutorial, but I'm blocking on a point of the tutorial.

Here is the code provided :

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

But I actually don't understand at all how the variables "W" (The weight) and "b" (The bias) are changed while the computing ?
On each batch, they are initialized at zero, but after ?
I don't see at all where in the code they're going to change ?

Thanks you very much in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TensorFlow [variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/variables/index.html) maintain their state from one `run()` call to the next. In your program they will be initialized to zero, and then progressively updated in the training loop.

The code that changes the values of the variables is created, implicitly, by this line:

```
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

In TensorFlow, a [`tf.train.Optimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#optimizers) is a class that creates operations for updating variables, typically based on the gradient of some tensor (e.g. a loss) with respect to those variables. By default, when you
call [`Optimizer.minimize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.minimize), TensorFlow creates operations to update **all variables** on which the given tensor (in this case `cross_entropy`) depends.

When you call `sess.run(train_step)`, this runs a graph that includes those update operations, and therefore instructs TensorFlow to update the values of the variables.

Comment: Wow many thanks!
I wasn't understing this since this morning! Was totally stuck. A great thank to you!

Comment: If you look at the docs for the base Optimizer class (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer), you will see that minimize() combines two operations. It calculates the gradients for the weights and biases and applies them to the respective weights and biases in the graph. GradientDescentOptimizer is a subclass of Optimizer implementing the basic SGD algorithm.